# Where to ask questions about animations created with OpenToonz?

Tags: discussion

Recently a new open source project was created called OpenToonz. OpenToonz is software for creating 2D animations (whether small and low res or full length feature films with high res 8k frames (See "Studio Ghibli". One of the main users of OpenToonz.)

**Where on stackexchange could I ask questions about 2D animation and OpenToonz? Would this stackexchange be a place to ask (I'm pretty sure the answer is no. given the FAQ/about/name-of-the-url)?**

I tried superuser.com but didn't get any response. I saw graphicdesign.stackexchange has an animation tag but the description of the tag IMO sounds like small animations or single frame type questions.

**Maybe a new animation stackexchange needs to be created?**

(For general animation questions whether by hand or by OpenToonz. Or maybe limit it to only 2D animation.)

Comment: This is not the place, but the project sounds interesting. I'm not sure a suitable SE site exists yet, so you might consider [proposing a new one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @gandalf3 hey for the Blender Area51 proposal what section did you put it under: arts, recreation, technology, professional, etc?

Comment: It's up to you, what category do you think your idea of the site fits under most? (perhaps have a [look at the faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) if you haven't already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would definatly be off topic here on this site. We are for everything blender.

As you correctly discovered there is no *good* SE site now.
I would say try on [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) they do have some animation questions using after effects and [adobe animate](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69465/is-adobe-animate-cc-suitable-for-these-animations), which are similarish.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will accept but I also agree with @gandalf3 comments, in addition to your answer, that creating a new SE is also a possible way forward.